# ¿Cómo calcular factorial de un número en Pseint?

Tags: pseint, pseudocódigo

Amigos, estoy tratando de calcular el factorial con pseudocódigo de Pseint.

```
Algoritmo algo1
    Leer num
    cont<-0 
    fact<-1 
    repetir
    fact<-fact*num 
    cont<-cont+1 
    hasta que (cont<=num)
        Escribir fact
        
FinAlgoritmo
```

Lastimosamente, no me da el resultado correcto, lo ejecuto y da el mismo valor

```
> 5
5
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y porque decis que mo da?

Answer (score 0):

Esta mal tu esquema de factorial. Estás multiplicando el numero muchas veces por si mismo (estas elevando el numero por si mismo, 5 elevado a 5 es 3125), tienes que multiplicar el contador por el numero factorial.

```
cont=cont+1
fact=fact*cont
```

(eso debería estar dentro del bucle)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que repases la definición de factorial, por ejemplo, en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

El algoritmo de forma iterativa puede quedar como:

```
Proceso sin_titulo
    Definir numero Como Entero;
    Definir contador Como Entero;
    definir factorial Como Entero;
    Leer numero;
    contador<-1;
    factorial<-1;
    Mientras contador<numero Hacer
        contador<-contador+1;
        factorial<-factorial*contador;
    Fin Mientras
    Escribir factorial;
FinProceso
```

De forma alternativa, se puede plantear definiendo una función recursiva, es decir, que se llame a si misma:

```
SubProceso f<- Factorial ( n )
    definir f Como Entero;
    Si n <0 Entonces
        escribir "Error factorial solo definido para número naturales";
        f<--1;
    Sino 
        Si n<=1 Entonces
            f =1;
        SiNo
            f<-Factorial(n-1)*n;
        FinSi
    FinSi
Fin SubProceso

Proceso sin_titulo
    Definir n Como Entero;
    Leer n;
    Definir f Como Entero;
    f<-Factorial(n);
    Escribir f; 
FinProceso
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar este pseudocódigo:

```
Definir num Como Entero
Definir contador Como Entero
Definir factorial Como Entero
Escribir 'Por favor digite un numero entero'
Leer num;
contador = 1
factorial = 1
Para contador=1 Hasta num Hacer 
    factorial = factorial*contador  
FinPara
Escribir 'El factorial del numero ingresado es: ',factorial;
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución puede ser

```
Algoritmo FactorialdeunNumero
    Definir nFactorial, contador, sub_factorial  Como Entero
    Escribir 'ingresa un numero: '
    Leer nFactorial
    contador = 1
    sub_factorial = 1
    
    Para contador = 1 Hasta nFactorial Con Paso 1 Hacer
        sub_factorial = sub_factorial * contador
        Imprimir nFactorial,'! = ', sub_factorial
    Fin Para
    Imprimir 'Resultado de Factorizar ',nFactorial,'! = ', sub_factorial
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu pseudocódigo reside en la condición de terminación del bucle y en la inicialización de la variable cont. Para calcular el factorial de un número correctamente, deberías incrementar cont desde 1 hasta el número para el cual deseas calcular el factorial, no desde 0. Además, el bucle debería continuar mientras cont sea menor o igual a num, no después de alcanzar ese valor. Aquí te muestro cómo corregir tu algoritmo:

```
Algoritmo CalculoFactorial
    Leer num
    cont <- 1 
    fact <- 1 
    repetir
        fact <- fact * cont 
        cont <- cont + 1 
    hasta que (cont > num)
    Escribir fact
FinAlgoritmo
```

Aunque tambien te recomiende que visites este articulo que tambien trata sobre [como calcular el factorial de un numero utilizando pseint](https://informaticamaestra.com/calcular-el-factorial-de-un-numero-en-pseint/).

Comment: Tenés una manera bastante particular de redactar respuestas... Solo por si acaso: [El uso de IA generativa (ej.: ChatGPT) está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462) y [¿Por qué publicar respuestas generadas por GPT y ChatGPT actualmente no es aceptable?](/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: tranquilo, soy redacto con años de experiencia.